# Android dependency has different version for the compile (27.1.1) and runtime (28.0.0-rc01)

Tags: android, flutter

I am stuck with this error when trying to run my Flutter app on a Pixel 2 emulator with Android 28. It worked the day before, but then it stopped working. Thanks for the help.

Here's the full error message:

> Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
>   Android dependency 'com.android.support:support-core-utils' has different version for the compile (27.1.1) and runtime (28.0.0-rc01) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

```
Flutter doctor:

/work/sdk/flutter/bin/flutter doctor --verbose
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.0.0, on Mac OS X 10.14.3 18D109, locale en-BE)
    • Flutter version 1.0.0 at /work/sdk/flutter
    • Framework revision 5391447fae (3 months ago), 2018-11-29 19:41:26 -0800
    • Engine revision 7375a0f414
    • Dart version 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /work/sdk/Android
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /work/sdk/Android
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 10.1, Build version 10B61
    • ios-deploy 1.9.4
    • CocoaPods version 1.6.0

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 33.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 182.5215
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)

[!] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2018.3.4)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • For information about installing plugins, see
      https://flutter.io/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: Can you post build.gradle?